# Odd behavior with std::async

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, stdasync

Consider the following sample code:

```
#include <future>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::array<int, 5> foo_t;

foo_t* bar(foo_t& foo) {
   return &foo;
}

int main() {
   foo_t foo;
   auto a = std::async(bar, foo);
   auto b = std::async(bar, foo);
   assert(a.get() == b.get());
   return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.6.3 compiles this with no complaints.  However, this fails at runtime with:

```
test: test.cpp:15: int main(): Assertion `a.get() == b.get()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

GCC 4.8.2, however, refuses to compile the file:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/future:38:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<std::array<int, 5ul>* (*(std::array<int, 5ul>))(std::array<int, 5ul>&)>':
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1525:70:   required from 'std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::array<int, 5ul>* (&)(std::array<int, 5ul>&); _Args = {std::array<int, 5ul>&}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = std::array<int, 5ul>*]'
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1541:36:   required from 'std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::array<int, 5ul>* (&)(std::array<int, 5ul>&); _Args = {std::array<int, 5ul>&}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = std::array<int, 5ul>*]'
test.cpp:13:30:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::array<int, 5ul>* (*(std::array<int, 5ul>))(std::array<int, 5ul>&)>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::array<int, 5ul>* (*(std::array<int, 5ul>))(std::array<int, 5ul>&)>'
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

This appears to be a libstdc++ issue.

So my questions are:
1 - should GCC reject this code, or is there something in the standard that I am not aware of.
2 - should the assertion fail?  The expected behavior is that async functions that take the same reference should refer to the same object, but it appears that a copy is made local to the async task.

I've tried compiling with clang, but it has the same compile error issues (as it shares the same libstdc++) with 4.8.2, and it can't compile the 4.6.3 library headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, gcc should reject this code. `std::async` copies the arguments and forwards them as rvalues. You cannot bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference, so this fails. If you want to pass by reference use `std::ref(foo)`. In this specific example, the call to `std::async(bar,foo)` essentially does the following:

   ```
   template<typename F>
   future<foo_t*> async(F& func,foo_t& arg){
       F func_copy(func);
       foo_t arg_copy(arg);
       // on background thread
       internal_set_future_result(func_copy(std::move(arg_copy)));
       return ...;
   }
   ```
2. If you use `std::ref(foo)` then the assertion should not fail. If the code doesn't compile then it's a moot point.

Comment: Please add more explanation to these parts: *"std::async copies the arguments"* and *"You cannot bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference"*. I am sure you are right but the answer, as it currently is, confuses me. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a very rare example of C++ thinking it knows better than you... one would think they would use perfect forwarding and assume that the user knows what they are doing.  In any case, the compile error is fairly obtuse.  Thanks for the clarification.